# legend not showing properly in d3

Tags: d3.js

Can any of you let me know why the legend is not showing properly in my code. I paste the link of the blocks here: https://bl.ocks.org/abrahamdu/2038544bffad6b5b25760b42ef519a7e

Comment: I see a legend (default blocks view may be too narrow:  bl.ocks.org/abrahamdu/raw/2038544bffad6b5b25760b42ef519a7e).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `x` position for both rectangles and texts:

```
legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width + 10)
    //etc...

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 10)
    //etc...
```

You may think that it puts them next to the right border of the SVG, but it doesn't: the parent `<g>` element is being translated to `width/2`. Thus, those legends are way outside the SVG limits.

**Solution**: Don't translate those `<g>` elements...

```
.attr("transform", function(d,i){ return "translate(0," + i * 30 + ")";});
//look at the zero here ----------------------------^
```

... and use `radius` to set the rectangles and texts positions:

```
legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", radius + 30)
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 30
};
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#0095D9", "#9C9536", "#F5E837"]);

var data = [{
  "type": "Sky",
  "pop": 0.75
}, {
  "type": "Shady side of pyramid",
  "pop": 0.07
}, {
  "type": "Sunny side of pyramid",
  "pop": 0.18
}];

var g = d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 1.8 + "," + height / 1.6 + ")");

var pie = d3.pie().sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.pop;
  })(data);

var arc = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0)
  .startAngle(function(d) {
    return d.startAngle + Math.PI * 1.2;
  })
  .endAngle(function(d) {
    return d.endAngle + Math.PI * 1.2;
  });;

var label = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(radius - 10);

var pyramid = g.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

pyramid.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.type);
  });

var legend = pyramid.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", 20)
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(pie)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 30 + ")";
  });

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", radius + 30)
  .attr("y", 9.5)
  .attr("dy", "0.32em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.type;
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", radius + 10)
  .attr("width", 19)
  .attr("height", 19)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.type);
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```